# Mini CMS - need some advices on pages

Tags: php, url, frameworks

I am going to write a super small cms with https://github.com/panique/mini/

Now I want to add a small pages section in the Admin of the site (this can be done easily ).
The advice part comes here:
The url of the mini framework is mostly easy, its /controller/method ( if its the index method then it won't needed to be shown in the url ).
So there is a file which checks if the controller is existing so it can load it.
But the thing is an user is not going to create a controller every time after creating a page.
What would be the best approach to do this ?

This file is checking if that controller exist: https://github.com/panique/mini/blob/master/application/core/application.php

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The way this handles routing, is much like CodeIgniter. The path would be `controller/method/arg1/arg2/arg3...`, so you can write a controller, define a method which accepts one (or more) arguments to load user pages.

Assume, user has created a page named `news`. He/She may load the page via URL `pages/view/news`.